# std:: isn't working for me

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to use Visual Studio 2015 to make a C++ dll.  Nothing is underlined as an error, but when I try to build it, errors are reported.  I am then asked if I want to run the last working version though there has never been a previous working version so that fails too.  The errors are all related to things not being members of `std::`.  I think I've included everything I need. Why this isn't working?

Here's the main dll code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "scan.h"

#define SerializerFunc 0xA1B010
#define WorkspaceVTable 0x1165EBC
#define InstanceSetParent 0x5249C0

std::string RBXMX_FileName;
std::ofstream RBXMX_Out;

struct instance_shared_ptr {
    void* instance;
    void* unk;
};

//typedef int(__thiscall* _ffc)(void* instance, std::string childname, char recursive);
typedef void(__cdecl* _serialize)(std::ostream&, std::vector<instance_shared_ptr>, ULONG);
typedef char(__thiscall* _SetParentInstance)(void* self, int wot, int whatever);
_SetParentInstance SetParentInstance;
//_ffc findfirstchild;
_serialize serialize;
DWORD WorkspaceVT;
DWORD Workspace;
DWORD Terrain;

BOOL Dump_Instance_Vector(std::ostream& export_stream, std::vector<instance_shared_ptr>* instance_vector)
{
    serialize(export_stream, *instance_vector, NULL);
    return TRUE;
}

std::string* GetName(int Instance) {
    return (std::string*)(*(int*)(Instance + 0x28));
}

int GetChildByName(int Instance, std::string Name) {
    // iterate over the children vector
    DWORD StartOfChildren = *(DWORD*)(Instance + 0x2C);
    DWORD EndOfChildren = *(DWORD*)(StartOfChildren + 4);
    for (int i = *(int*)StartOfChildren; i != EndOfChildren; i += 8)
        if (strcmp(GetName(*(int*)i)->c_str(), Name.c_str()) == 0)
            return *(int*)i;
    return 0;
}

/*
void RemoveTerrainFromWorkspace(int Workspace)
{
DWORD StartOfChildren = *(DWORD*)(Workspace + 0x2C);
DWORD EndOfChildren = *(DWORD*)(StartOfChildren + 4);
for (int i = *(int*)StartOfChildren; i != EndOfChildren; i += 8)
if (strcmp(GetName(*(int*)i)->c_str(), "Terrain") == 0)
*(int*)i = NULL;
}
*/

int __stdcall MessageBoxHook(HWND WindowParent, LPCSTR Body, LPCSTR Caption, UINT Type)
{
    MessageBoxW(WindowParent, L"The place has successfully been dumped! Roblox will now close.", L"Magus Night", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    PostMessage(GetConsoleWindow(), WM_CLOSE, NULL, NULL);
    std::exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}

// crash rate: ~40%
// please excuse the terrible code (this was made in 5 minutes)
VOID Init()
{
    std::stringstream RBXMX_Log;
    DWORD OldPerm, OldPermMsg, Base;

    // open console
    VirtualProtect(&FreeConsole, 1, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &OldPerm);
    VirtualProtect(&MessageBoxA, 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &OldPerm);
    *(BYTE*)(&FreeConsole) = 0xC3;
    AllocConsole();
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);
    SetConsoleTitleA("Place Stealer - by Louka @ V3rmillion");

    // header/filestream stuff
    std::cout << "Place Stealer - by Louka @ V3rmillion\nIf the game crashes during the dumping process, just try again.\n\nPlease enter filename: ";
    getline(std::cin, RBXMX_FileName);
    RBXMX_Out = std::ofstream(RBXMX_FileName, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
    if (RBXMX_Out.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "\nSomething went wrong while opening the file. Close Roblox and try again.";
        return;
    }

    // get functions from their offset
    std::cout << "[1/3] Getting funcs... ";
    Base = (DWORD)GetModuleHandleA("RobloxPlayerBeta.exe");
    serialize = (_serialize)(SerializerFunc - 0x400000 + Base);
    //SerializerJumpTo = (SerializerBckt - 0x400000 + Base);
    SetParentInstance = (_SetParentInstance)(InstanceSetParent - 0x400000 + Base);
    std::cout << "OK!\n[2/3] Obtaining workspace children vector... ";

    // obtain the workspace service by scanning its vftable
    WorkspaceVT = (WorkspaceVTable - 0x400000 + Base);
    Workspace = Memory::Scan(PAGE_READWRITE, (char*)&WorkspaceVT, "xxxx");
    if (strcmp(GetName(Workspace)->c_str(), "Workspace"))
    {
        std::cout << "Wrong Workspace instance! Quit Roblox and try again.";
        return;
    }

    // save the thing
    std::cout << "OK!\n[3/3] Dumping place to file... ";
    Terrain = GetChildByName(Workspace, "Terrain");
    //*(DWORD*)(Terrain + 0x22) = 0;
    //*(DWORD*)(Terrain + 0x34) = NULL;
    //RemoveTerrainFromWorkspace(Workspace);
    try
    {
        SetParentInstance((void*)Terrain, NULL, TRUE);
        Dump_Instance_Vector(RBXMX_Out, (std::vector<instance_shared_ptr>*)(Workspace + 0x2C));
    }
    catch (std::exception e)
    {
        std::cout << "An error occured while dumping: " << e.what() << "\n";
        return;
    }
    //Serialize_Instances(RBXMX_Out, *(std::vector<instance_shared_ptr>*)(Workspace + 0x2C), NULL);
    *(BYTE*)(&MessageBoxA) = 0xE9;
    *(DWORD*)((DWORD)&MessageBoxA + 1) = ((DWORD)&MessageBoxHook - (DWORD)&MessageBoxA) - 5;
    std::cout << "OK!\nDump successful!";
    RBXMX_Out.close();
}
```

and here's the scan.h file:

```
namespace Memory {
    bool Compare(const BYTE *pData, const BYTE *bMask, const char *szMask)
    {
        for (; *szMask; ++szMask, ++pData, ++bMask)
            if (*szMask == 'x' && *pData != *bMask) return 0;
        return (*szMask) == NULL;
    }
    DWORD FindPattern(DWORD dwAddress, DWORD dwLen, BYTE *bMask, char *szMask)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)dwLen; i++)
            if (Compare((BYTE*)(dwAddress + (int)i), bMask, szMask))  return (int)(dwAddress + i);
        return 0;
    }
    int Scan(DWORD mode, char* content, char* mask)
    {
        DWORD PageSize;
        SYSTEM_INFO si;
        GetSystemInfo(&si);
        PageSize = si.dwPageSize;
        MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mi;
        for (DWORD lpAddr = 0; lpAddr < 0x7FFFFFFF; lpAddr += PageSize)
        {
            DWORD vq = VirtualQuery((void*)lpAddr, &mi, PageSize);
            if (vq == ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER || vq == 0) break;
            if (mi.Type == MEM_MAPPED) continue;
            if (mi.Protect == mode)
            {
                int addr = FindPattern(lpAddr, PageSize, (PBYTE)content, mask);
                if (addr != 0)
                {
                    return addr;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2039   'string': is not a member of 'std'  Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  13  
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  13  
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'RBXMX_FileName'    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  13  
Error   C2039   'ofstream': is not a member of 'std'    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  14  
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  14  
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'RBXMX_Out' Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  14  
Error   C2039   'ostream': is not a member of 'std' Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  22  
Error   C2065   'ostream': undeclared identifier    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  22  
Error   C2059   syntax error: ','   Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  22  
Error   C2039   'vector': is not a member of 'std'  Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  22  
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  26  
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'serialize' Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  26  
Error   C2039   'ostream': is not a member of 'std' Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  31  
Error   C2065   'ostream': undeclared identifier    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  31  
Error   C2065   'export_stream': undeclared identifier  Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  31  
Error   C2039   'vector': is not a member of 'std'  Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  31  
Error   C2065   'vector': undeclared identifier Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  31  
Error   C2275   'instance_shared_ptr': illegal use of this type as an expression    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  31  
Error   C2065   'instance_vector': undeclared identifier    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  31  
Error   C2448   'Dump_Instance_Vector': function-style initializer appears to be a function definition  Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  32  
Error   C2039   'string': is not a member of 'std'  Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  37  
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '*'    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  37  
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  37  
Error   C2086   'int string': redefinition  Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  37  
Error   C2059   syntax error: '{'   Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  37  
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '{'    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  37  
Error   C2447   '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)   Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  37  
Error   C2039   'string': is not a member of 'std'  Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  41  
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'string'   Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  41  
Error   C2227   left of '->c_str' must point to class/struct/union/generic type Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  46  
Error   C2065   'Name': undeclared identifier   Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  46  
Error   C2228   left of '.c_str' must have class/struct/union   Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  46  
Error   C2660   'strcmp': function does not take 1 arguments    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  46  
Error   C2039   'exit': is not a member of 'std'    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  66  
Error   C3861   'exit': identifier not found    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  66  
Error   C2039   'stringstream': is not a member of 'std'    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  74  
Error   C2065   'stringstream': undeclared identifier   Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  74  
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'RBXMX_Log' Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  74  
Error   C2065   'RBXMX_Log': undeclared identifier  Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  74  
Error   C2065   'stdout': undeclared identifier Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  82  
Error   C3861   'freopen': identifier not found Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  82  
Error   C2065   'stdin': undeclared identifier  Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  83  
Error   C3861   'freopen': identifier not found Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  83  
Error   C2039   'cout': is not a member of 'std'    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  87  
Error   C2065   'cout': undeclared identifier   Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  87  
Error   C2039   'cin': is not a member of 'std' Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  88  
Error   C2065   'cin': undeclared identifier    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  88  
Error   C2065   'RBXMX_FileName': undeclared identifier Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  88  
Error   C3861   'getline': identifier not found Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  88  
Error   C2065   'RBXMX_Out': undeclared identifier  Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  89  
Error   C2039   'ofstream': is not a member of 'std'    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  89  
Error   C2065   'RBXMX_FileName': undeclared identifier Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  89  
Error   C3083   'ios_base': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  89  
Error   C2039   'out': is not a member of 'std' Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  89  
Error   C2065   'out': undeclared identifier    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  89  
Error   C2039   'binary': is not a member of 'std'  Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  89  
Error   C2065   'binary': undeclared identifier Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  89  
Error   C2065   'RBXMX_Out': undeclared identifier  Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  90  
Error   C2228   left of '.fail' must have class/struct/union    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  90  
Error   C2039   'cout': is not a member of 'std'    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  92  
Error   C2065   'cout': undeclared identifier   Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  92  
Error   C2039   'cout': is not a member of 'std'    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  97  
Error   C2065   'cout': undeclared identifier   Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  97  
Error   C2065   'serialize': undeclared identifier  Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  99  
Error   C2064   term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  99  
Error   C2039   'cout': is not a member of 'std'    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  102 
Error   C2065   'cout': undeclared identifier   Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  102 
Error   C2227   left of '->c_str' must point to class/struct/union/generic type Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  107 
Error   C2039   'cout': is not a member of 'std'    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  109 
Error   C2065   'cout': undeclared identifier   Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  109 
Error   C2039   'cout': is not a member of 'std'    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  114 
Error   C2065   'cout': undeclared identifier   Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  114 
Error   C2660   'GetChildByName': function does not take 2 arguments    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  115 
Error   C2065   'RBXMX_Out': undeclared identifier  Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  122 
Error   C2039   'vector': is not a member of 'std'  Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  122 
Error   C2065   'vector': undeclared identifier Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  122 
Error   C2275   'instance_shared_ptr': illegal use of this type as an expression    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  122 
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  122 
Error   C2039   'exception': is not a member of 'std'   Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  124 
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'exception'    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  124 
Error   C2310   catch handlers must specify one type    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  124 
Error   C2039   'cout': is not a member of 'std'    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  126 
Error   C2065   'cout': undeclared identifier   Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  126 
Error   C2065   'e': undeclared identifier  Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  126 
Error   C2228   left of '.what' must have class/struct/union    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  126 
Error   C2039   'cout': is not a member of 'std'    Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  132 
Error   C2065   'cout': undeclared identifier   Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  132 
Error   C2065   'RBXMX_Out': undeclared identifier  Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  133 
Error   C2228   left of '.close' must have class/struct/union   Place Stealer   c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\place stealer\place stealer\place stealer.cpp  133
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks again!

Comment: Can you share the errors with us?

Comment: by the way, you want your precompiled header to be included before any other headers

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_SetParentInstance`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them.

Comment: The errors may have to do with the improper usage of `#include "stdafx.h"` As @jaggedSpire mentioned move it up above the other includes.

Comment: @NathanOliver I've added the errors.

Comment: So, where is the code of that `place stealer.cpp` file, where all the errors occur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using precompiled headers, the compiler believes that the file always starts with `#include "stdafx.h"`, and skips everything coming before that.

So just reorder your includes so that `#include "stdafx.h"` is the first one.

Comment: Awesome, I knew the requirement was for the pch to be included first, but I didn't know the consequences of not doing that. As an aside, I would mention that "stdafx.h" is only the default name that VS uses for the precompiled header -- someone else's pch may be named differently and this advice still applies (but they may be confused when visiting this post)